# Verify a Tautology without a truth table.

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

Verify that the following are tautologies. Do not make truth tables.

a. $\lnot(\lnot) P \leftrightarrow P$

The first question is just a double negation law. So, if I have to take the left side and make it equivalent to the right side, then I would just use the double negation law on the left which will result in $P \leftrightarrow P$.

$\lnot(\lnot) P \leftrightarrow P$ (double negation )

$P \leftrightarrow P$.

---

b. $\lnot (P \lor Q) \leftrightarrow \lnot P \land \lnot Q$
This is one of the DeMorgan's Law. If I want the left side to be equivalent as the right side, won't I have to use one of DeMorgan's Laws to achieve that result?

Edit: I had to find some of my notes from last night. 
I got this for b because it may be equivalent to 
$\lnot P \land \lnot Q \leftrightarrow \lnot P \land \lnot Q$ from c

c.$\lnot (P \land Q) \leftrightarrow \lnot P \lor \lnot Q$
This is also a DeMorgan's law. Again, should I use one of DeMorgan's Laws as well?

$\lnot P \lor \lnot Q \leftrightarrow \lnot P \lor \lnot Q$ from b

$\lnot (P \land Q) \leftrightarrow \lnot (P \land Q)$

---

d. $P \land (Q \lor R) \leftrightarrow (P \land Q) \lor (P \land R)$

This is the distributive law. I'm wondering if I should just distribute the $P \land$ on the left to make it equivalent to the right side.

$P \land (Q \lor R) \leftrightarrow (P \land Q) \lor (P \land R)$

$P \land  Q  \space \lor P \land  R \leftrightarrow (P \land Q) \lor (P \land R)$ (distributive law)

$(P \land  Q)  \space \lor (P \land  R) \leftrightarrow (P \land Q) \lor (P \land R)$

Edit: What if I substitute $A$ for $P$ and $B$ for $(Q \lor R)$?

I'm starting from the left $P \land (Q \lor R)$

So, let $P=A$ and $(Q \lor R) = B$?

then we have $A \land B$

Using Double Negation

$\lnot(\lnot P) \leftrightarrow P$

we obtain

$ \lnot (\lnot A) \land \lnot (\lnot B)$

The first part of DeMorgan's Law states that $\lnot (P \lor Q) \leftrightarrow \lnot P \land \lnot Q$

Therefore,
$\lnot(\lnot(\lnot A) \lor \lnot (\lnot B))$

Using Double Negation Law

$\lnot (A \lor B)$

Substitute back

$\lnot (P \lor (Q \lor R))$

Well that somewhat worked but if I were to use the distributive law now, I would have a lot of $\lor$ signs

$\lnot [( P \lor Q) \lor (P \lor \lor R)]$

unless the $\lor \lor$ changes into an $\land$ ? And the $\lnot$ sticks around which doesn't happen on the right side of d.

---

e. $P \lor (Q \land R) \leftrightarrow (P \lor Q) \land (P \lor R)$

This is also a distributive law, so maybe I should distribute the $P \lor$

$P \lor (Q \land R) \leftrightarrow (P \lor Q) \land (P \lor R)$

$P \lor Q \land P \lor R \leftrightarrow (P \lor Q) \land (P \lor R)$ (distributive law)

$(P \lor Q) \land (P \lor R) \leftrightarrow (P \lor Q) \land (P \lor R)$

Edit:
I am using the left side of e which is $P \lor (Q \land R)$

Let $A=P$ and $B=(Q \land R )$

$A \lor B$

Using Double Negation

$\lnot(\lnot P) \leftrightarrow P$

$\lnot (\lnot A) \lor \lnot (\lnot B)$

DeMorgan's Law from C.

$\lnot (\lnot (\lnot A) \land \lnot (\lnot B))$

Double negation

$\lnot ( A \land B)$

Substituting Back

$\lnot (P \land (Q \land R)$

Distributive Law.

$\lnot ( (P \land Q) \land (P \land \land R))$

There has got to be a way to get rid of the $\lnot$ and the extra symbol in D and E

Comment: Your question is unclear.  In (c): yes, go ahead and use DeMorgan's laws. In (d), sure, why not distribute?  In the other parts it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: The book itself was unclear to begin with. I had no clue about "citing the appropriate result". I don't understand that part at all. Had this problem allow me to draw truth tables, I would've been done ages ago. 
[my book page](http://assets.openstudy.com/updates/attachments/52db9a37e4b05a53debd0b77-usukidoll-1390123624453-scan1401170001.jpg)

Comment: When assignment instructions are unclear, the best thing for you to do is contact your instructor for clarification.  My guess is that your methods (DeMorgan's, distributive law, etc.) are exactly what the author of the problem is looking for.

Comment: that's what I'm doing. I just contacted the instructor through email. But, hmm I don't know if I'm doing this right... Do I have to take the left side of each problem and use the laws to achieve the result from the right side like...let's take 
$\lnot(\lnot P) \leftrightarrow P$
I see a double negation...I'm taking the left side. 

So do I use the double negation law to make $\lnot(\lnot P)$  $P$ ?
So, this would be the end result
$P \leftrightarrow P$

Comment: Yes, that's the usual idea. However, you should check with your instructor about how you are expected to format your arguments.  Notice that the last lines of your work for (c), (d) and (e) are tautologies, so they don't say anything.  You are actually writing more than you need to, and starting with an expression you haven't shown to be true.  Again, check with your instructor about how you should do this kind of thing.

Comment: I'm writing more? SO c d and e could be just a one line proof right? Like for d and e on the left side. To make it like the right side distribute the P and add parenthesis or something...........

Comment: Yes.  Start with the left side, and show it is equivalent to something, and perhaps show that something is equivalent to something else, etc., and end with the right-hand side that in the first line.  Connect each equivalent expression with $\leftrightarrow$, and be sure to give your justifications.

Comment: I think that, if you must not use truth-tables, you must exploit Completeness Theorem for propositional logic, that says that every tautology is provable starting from some specified set of axioms and using some (at least one) rules of inference (like *modus ponens*). So, we need to know what are the axioms you are authorized to use. Otherwise, I suppose that your "verification" of *(b)* (one of De Morgan's laws) using *(c)* (another De Morgan's law) and subsequently verifying *(c)* with an appeal to *(b)* is plainly circular ... so I'm not sure it will work.

Comment: whoa ok first of all I have no idea what the Completeness Theorem is...it's not in my book. Also professor just did truth tables and moved on to show a simple proof in the last lecture which had nothing to do with the assignment I was given. 
I'm not sure if I'm on the right track though for d and e .. for d I started with the left side and just used a distributive law property to have the $P \land$ distributed until it looked like the right hand side
and for e it was the same thing only using distributive law for $ P \lor$

Comment: Ok, I understand. Forgetting about Completeness, I'm trying to understand what a "verification" must look like. If you are trying to prove a tautology, you must start with a set of "adimissible moves" and with a "starting configuration", like a chess play. So, using, distributive law is fine, but (I think) you cannot use "move c" until you haven't proved it.

Comment: until I haven't proved it? What does that mean? move C? you mean when I distributed the $P \land$ for problem d?

Ok here is problem d
$P \land (Q \lor R) \leftrightarrow (P \land Q) \lor (P \land R)$

so if I wanted to start at the left side I have to use $P \land (Q \lor R) $ and somehow use some rules or laws to have the result like the right side which is $(P \land Q) \lor (P \land R)$

Comment: I'll try with the simple example; you must verify that $\lnot (\lnot P) \leftrightarrow P$ is a tautology. You are saying : apply double-negation law, and we convert the formula into $P \leftrightarrow P$, that is a tautology (why? ... without using truth-tables, what is your definition of tautology?). But now, the double-negation law you are appealing to is exactly : $\lnot (\lnot P) \leftrightarrow P$; so what have we "verified" ?

Comment: that they are equivalent to each other

blah I accidentally pressed save. so anyway the definition of a tautology is that everything is true. In the truth table, there is an all truth column. Should there be an all false column, there is a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We verify *b)* and *c)* (De Morgan's laws) using *a)* (double-negation law).

*a)* $\lnot (\lnot P) \leftrightarrow P$.

*b)* - Start with the left-hand side and put $\lnot \lnot P$ in place of $P$ and $\lnot \lnot Q$ in place of $Q$ (i.e., use double-negation *a)*) :

$\lnot (P \lor Q) \leftrightarrow \lnot (\lnot \lnot P \lor \lnot \lnot Q)$

then use *c)* to transform the content of right-hand side parentheses into : $\lnot (\lnot P \land \lnot Q)$ [ rewrite it as : $\lnot [\lnot (\lnot P) \lor \lnot (\lnot Q) ]$ ; now it is of the "form" : $\lnot [\lnot P_1 \lor \lnot Q_1]$; then you must replace $\lnot P_1 \lor \lnot Q_1$ with $\lnot (P_1 \land Q_1)$, by *c)*, that is really : $\lnot (\lnot P \land \lnot Q)$]. In this way you will get :

$\lnot (P \lor Q) \leftrightarrow \lnot (\lnot \lnot P \lor \lnot \lnot Q) \leftrightarrow \lnot \lnot (\lnot P \land \lnot Q)$

then apply again double-negation to the right-hand side ("cancelling" $\lnot \lnot$) and you will have :

$\lnot (P \lor Q) \leftrightarrow (\lnot P \land \lnot Q)$.

*c)* - Start with the left-hand side and put $\lnot \lnot P$ in place of $P$ and $\lnot \lnot Q$ in place of $Q$ (i.e., use double-negation *a)*) :

$\lnot (P \land Q) \leftrightarrow \lnot (\lnot \lnot P \land \lnot \lnot Q)$

then use *b)* to transform the content of right-hand side parentheses into : $\lnot (\lnot P \lor \lnot Q)$ getting :

$\lnot (P \land Q) \leftrightarrow \lnot (\lnot \lnot P \land \lnot \lnot Q) \leftrightarrow \lnot \lnot (\lnot P \lor \lnot Q)$

then apply again double-negation and it's done.

Comment: How were you able to get this so fast? It took me a while to realize that the problems I was given were not ordinary. They were laws.

So if I were to solve b ... should I use double negation from a and the demorgan from c?

Comment: I've studied them long time ago ... this is the "magic". But as Matthew sayd, don't forget the "basic law of learning" : "if you don't understand, ask".

Comment: I am asking... but ok. I understand that were are using the left side of c
$\lnot (P \land Q) \leftrightarrow \lnot P \lor \lnot Q$
this is the left side
$\lnot (P \land Q)$ 
now I apply the double negation law from a for $P$ and $Q$
$\lnot (\lnot \lnot P \land \lnot \lnot Q)$
but I don't understand how to use b unless we are using b to transform $\lnot (\lnot \lnot P \land \lnot \lnot Q)$

Comment: No, we have proved the equivalence of $\lnot (P \land Q) $ and $ \lnot P \lor \lnot Q$ (i.e.of "second" De Morgan's law), assuming : doble-negation law, "first" De Morgan's law, transitivity of equivalence (the conncetive $\leftrightarrow$) and replacement properties (i.e. if in a formula $A$ with the propositional variable $P$ I replace all occurrences of $P$ with a formula $B$, the truth-value of the result does not change; we apply it - for example -when we replaced $P$ with $\lnot \lnot P$).

Comment: O_O that was lightning fast.
so b is $\lnot (P \lor Q) \leftrightarrow \lnot P \land \lnot Q$

oh I see how the double negation would occur again for $\lnot (P \land Q) \leftrightarrow \lnot (\lnot \lnot P \land \lnot \lnot Q) \leftrightarrow \lnot \lnot (\lnot P \lor \lnot Q)$
$\lnot \lnot [\lnot \lnot ( \lnot P \lor \lnot Q)$]

Comment: and then that would lead to $(\lnot P \lor \lnot Q)$

so for b it could be possible that I have to use the double negation law and the second demorgan.

Comment: *1)*-st comment : we have done : $\lnot (P \land Q) \leftrightarrow \lnot (\lnot \lnot P \land \lnot \lnot Q) \leftrightarrow \lnot \lnot ( \lnot P \lor \lnot Q) \leftrightarrow (\lnot P \lor \lnot Q)$. The equivalences works "both way"; you must not redouble $\lnot \lnot$, you read the law form right to left (i.e. $P \leftrightarrow \lnot \lnot P$) and you can cancel the couple of $\lnot$s in front of the formula into parentheses.

Comment: *2)*-nd comment : Yes; you can apply the same "process" starting with $\lnot (P \lor Q)$ and using the double-negation law and the previous work to get $\lnot P \land \lnot Q$.

Comment: alright so for b we have
$\lnot (P \lor Q) \leftrightarrow (\lnot P \land \lnot Q)$
the left side of the equation is 
$\lnot (P \lor Q)$
using the double negation law from a we have the following result
 $\lnot (\lnot \lnot P \lor  \lnot \lnot Q)$

Comment: the second demorgan law, c, is
$\lnot (P \land Q) \leftrightarrow \lnot P \lor \lnot Q$
we need to transform the content from b by using c?

Comment: Yes; and then you go on. If you write it as : $\lnot ( \lnot (\lnot P) \lor \lnot (\lnot Q) )$ you can "see" the next move : use *c)* to replace inside the formula with $\lnot (\lnot P \land \lnot Q)$.

Comment: That's where the problem is. I'm trying to follow along with the previous problem, but I got lost somewhere probably because c isn't being shown when a and b is being used. 
ok replacing $\lnot ( \lnot (\lnot P) \lor \lnot (\lnot Q) )$ with $\lnot (\lnot P \land \lnot Q)$
so... $\lnot (\lnot P \land \lnot Q)$?

Comment: or that could be $\lnot P \land \lnot Q$?

Comment: or... $¬(¬(¬(\lnot P) \land¬(¬ (\lnot Q))$?
and maybe use double negation law from a again to have
$\lnot P \land \lnot Q$?

Comment: We verify *c)* starting form left and using what we already have; so you have correctly transformed $\lnot (P \lor Q)$ into $\lnot(\lnot \lnot P \lor \lnot \lnot Q)$ (exploiting double-negation). Then rewrite it as : $\lnot[\lnot (\lnot P) \lor \lnot (\lnot Q)]$ and replace the "inner" $\lnot (\lnot P) \lor \lnot (\lnot Q)$ with the corresponding *b)*, that is $\lnot [(\lnot P) \land (\lnot Q)]$.

Comment: ok well I have gotten $¬(¬P∧¬Q)$ so do I do a double negation again because the right hand side of b is $¬P∧¬Q $ which is what I want to get the only thing I could think of right now is double negating the whole equation but of course that's not going to work.

Comment: But now $\lnot (\lnot P \land \lnot Q)$ is "inside" $\lnot [ ...]$, so you really have : $\lnot [\lnot (...)]$ i.e. $\lnot \lnot (\lnot P \land \lnot Q)$. Now you apply double-negation (from left to right) so you can "cancel" the two outer $\lnot$ and get : $(\lnot P \land \lnot Q)$. Reading the "chain" of equivalences all together, you will have : $\lnot(P \lor Q) \leftrightarrow (\lnot P \land \lnot Q)$.

Comment: so using double negation $\lnot \lnot [\lnot \lnot (\lnot P \land \lnot Q)]$
the result will be $(\lnot P \land \lnot Q)$ ?

Comment: I'll edit the original answer.

Comment: thanks. I sort of understood the negation part but when I saw 

"¬(P∧Q)↔¬(¬¬P∧¬¬Q)

then use b) to transform the content of right-hand side parentheses into : ¬(¬P∨¬Q) getting :

¬(P∧Q)↔¬(¬¬P∧¬¬Q)↔¬¬(¬P∨¬Q)"

I got really lost.

Comment: what about for d and e? DO I just take the left hand side of the expression and apply the distributive law?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do these is with the [method of analytic tableaux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux). [I'll do (b) as an example and leave the rest as an exercise. I hope you don't mind :)]

You start with the negation of the original formula then apply a series of contradiction-hunting rules to get

[image],

which is *closed* (i.e. its paths end in contradictions), meaning that the original formula was indeed a tautology.

[These notes (in pdf form)](http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/notes/logic.pdf) explain the method in detail.

Comment: The code for the diagram above can be found [here](https://www.writelatex.com/666024xvnptv#/1405796/).

Comment: I haven't learned this method :(
but you could tell me if I should just use the distributive laws for d and e... because they seem so straight forward, but I could be wrong.

Comment: That's okay. I get the impression that it's not widely used, perhaps because tableaux are fiddly to format. But it's my preferred method. The distributive law looks appropriate on the face of it $\ddot\smile$

Comment: really? wait I don't know what that means...yeah you could tell that I'm new at this.. but I do know that I have to use the left side of d and somehow get it to be the same as the right hand side. I figure distributing the $P \land$ might work and for e distribute the $P \lor$.

Comment: @Shaun - regarding tableau method, in addition to "my preferred" Smullyan's book, you can see also : Mordechai Ben-Ari, *Mathematical Logic for Computer Science* (3rd ed - 2012) and Marcello D'Agostino & Dov Gabbay (editors), *Handbook of Tableau Methods* (1998).